# Google Search Image "no longer available: 403"

Tags: google-search-api

I'm using this google API

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images
```

which was working fine till yesterday night. But from today(02-Dec-15) morning it says that "This API is no longer available.". Please look at the response return by this above API.

```
{
  "responseData": null,
  "responseDetails": "This API is no longer available.",
  "responseStatus": 403
}
```

I think, support to this API is stopped now by google(which was already officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011). 
https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide?hl=en

I'm writing this question to help others as well who are/will facing this issue. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/ may help out. I'm also reading the documentation over here and if someone already has answer pls submit.